# Programmatical configuring Microsoft.IdentityModel on ASP.NET application not working - Passive Redirect enabled but never worked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif

I am developing a claim based authentication app and wanted to move the Microsoft.IdentityModel configuration from web.config file to my codes to manage the configuration dynamically.

This was the federatedAuthentication section contained in web.config:

```
<federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="trust" realm="real" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
</federatedAuthentication>
```

I have tried to attach an EventHandler in Application_Start() method to implement the configuration in the codes instead of web.config file:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += new EventHandler<ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs>(FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated);
    }

    private static void FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(Object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string rpRealm = "realm";
        const bool requireSsl = false;
        const bool requireHttps = false;
        const bool passRedirect = true;
        const string issuer = "trust";

        ...

        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.PassiveRedirectEnabled = passRedirect;
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer = issuer;
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Realm = rpRealm;
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RequireHttps = requireHttps;

        ...
    }
```

When I removed the configurations in the web.config file and built the codes, the problem happened that the application did not redirect to the Issuer url even if the PassiveRedirectEnabled property was already set to true.

By putting breakpoints I confirmed that the codes above did run and did not generate exceptions; however, the passive redirection never worked.

P.S. I was using WIF 3.5; the assembly imported was Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @jonho for your kind help! However your codes work in *WIF 4.5*, whereas I am working with *WIF 3.5* and things are a little bit different here...

After researching around on the Internet and testing with my codes, I came up with a working solution with the help from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/41b9a137-faca-43c6-b965-01d5322df5f0/change-microsoftidentitymodel-configuration.

Just in case people might get stuck as I did, here's what I did:

1. Add an event handler when ServiceConfiguration is created, and add the allowed audience and certificate information in the event handler:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += 
                   new EventHandler<ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs>(FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated);
   }

   private static void FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(Object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
   {
       const string allowedAudience = "allowed_aud";
       const string certThumbprint = "thumb";
       const string certName = "name";

       var serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();

       serviceConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(allowedAudience));

       var issuerNameRegistry = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
       issuerNameRegistry.AddTrustedIssuer(certThumbprint, certName);
       serviceConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = issuerNameRegistry;
       serviceConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

       e.ServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration;
   }
   ```
2. Implement Application_AuthenticateRequest() method for the ASP.NET application. Provide the issuer information there:

   ```
   protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.RequireSsl = requireSsl;
       FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer = issuer;
       FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Realm = rpRealm;
       FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.PassiveRedirectEnabled = passRedirect;
       FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RequireHttps = requireHttps;
   }
   ```

This should be enough to make passive redirect working with ASP.NET application in WIF 3.5

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it - create a FederationConfiguration object, then add to it's WsFederationConfiguration property, then set the whole thing to the event args.

```
  private static void FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated(object sender, FederationConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    //from appsettings...
    const string allowedAudience = "http://audience1/user/get";
    const string rpRealm = "http://audience1/";
    const string domain = "";
    const bool requireSsl = false;
    const string issuer = "http://sts/token/create;
    const string certThumbprint = "mythumbprint";
    const string authCookieName = "StsAuth";

    var federationConfiguration = new FederationConfiguration();
                             federationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(allowedAudience));

    var issuingAuthority = new IssuingAuthority(internalSts);
    issuingAuthority.Thumbprints.Add(certThumbprint);
    issuingAuthority.Issuers.Add(internalSts);
    var issuingAuthorities = new List<IssuingAuthority> {issuingAuthority};

    var validatingIssuerNameRegistry = new ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry {IssuingAuthorities = issuingAuthorities};
    federationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = validatingIssuerNameRegistry;
    federationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

    var chunkedCookieHandler = new ChunkedCookieHandler {RequireSsl = false, Name = authCookieName, Domain = domain, PersistentSessionLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)};
    federationConfiguration.CookieHandler = chunkedCookieHandler;
    federationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Issuer = issuer;
    federationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.Realm = rpRealm;
    federationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration.RequireHttps = requireSsl;

    e.FederationConfiguration = federationConfiguration;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since your codes work in WIF 4.5 and I am working with WIF 3.5 I tweaked around the codes, did some researches and came up with a working solution! I posted my answers as well. Thanks!

Comment: X509CertificateValidationMode.None => is it safe ? We registered the thumbprint to issuingAuthority so the validation should be useless... ?

Comment: @Guillaume "X509CertificateValidationMode.None" is for testing purposes. I wrote a custom validator afterwards and changed it to "X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom"

Comment: @Endri - yes it does.  I have a full working prototype here https://github.com/seantarogers/SsoWsFederation this is with MVC 5.

Comment: @jonho your solution looks interesting. I am trying to get it running but I couldn't get to create the certificate specified. The link redirects to another article. I am using VS 2015 and windows 7. Can you tell me how to generate the certificate?

Comment: you can do it via IIS. have a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff710475(v=ws.10).aspx. the friendly name should be the name you look for in the certificateManager class https://github.com/seantarogers/SsoWsFederation/blob/master/SecurityTokenService/Managers/CertificateManager.cs

Comment: @jonho I have problem with MMC it says Microsoft Management Console has stopped working. Is there any other way without using MMC, or do you know anything that causes MMC to stop working? Sorry if these questions are off topic.

Comment: so you managed to generate a cert? and you have the friendly name? maybe you can just leave it in the personal cert store and just update the certificatemanager class with the friendlyname and run the solution.  I havent had MMC fail to start before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113158/discussion-between-endri-and-jonho).

Comment: Can't make it work for AspNetCore - instead of firing Created event, it still raises the error on accessing FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration property, asking for system.identityModel section (which should not be required anymore) for some reason.